# ProjectCracker with .netstandard 2.0 projects

Tags: f#, .net-standard, f#-compiler-services

My team has recently switched from using .net framework to use .net standard 2.0 for our F# libraries.  We have some internal scripts that we run on our projects to automatically generate markdown documentation, and these scripts use the F# Compiler Services SDK to analyze the code and retrieve the type metadata, documentation comments, etc.

We are using the `FSharp.Compiler.Service.ProjectCracker` library to read our `.fsproj` files and generate the `FSharpProjectOptions` instance to use when running the `FSharpChecker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject` method.  However, with the .net standard projects, we get the following error when calling `ProjectCracker.GetProjectOptionsFromProjectFile`:

````
System.Exception: Could not load project Example.fsproj in ProjectCollection. 
Available tools: 
["C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64";
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64";
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727";
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5";
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"]. 

Message: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. 
If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. 
If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.```
````

Is there any way to read .net standard project files using the Project Cracker library, or will we need to manually parse the file and create the `FSharpProjectOptions` by hand for our new libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the standard ProjectCracker package cannot be used to read .netstandard project files.  However, there is already a NuGet package available to provide this functionality, [Dotnet.ProjInfo](https://github.com/enricosada/dotnet-proj-info/tree/master/examples).  This project allows you to read all the variations of .NET project files, including .NET Framework and .NET Core, as well as both project.json and .csproj/.fsproj files.

The project isn't extremely well documented as an API (the documentation is better for the command-line tool), but programmatic usage of the tool can be seen in the [FsAutoComplete library](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete).

For a .netstandard project, you can use the `getProjectInfos` function, like so:

```
let getProjectInfo additionalMSBuildProps file =
    let projDir = Path.GetDirectoryName file
    let additionalInfo = 
            [ "OutputType"
              "IsTestProject"
              "Configuration"
              "IsPackable"
              MSBuildKnownProperties.TargetFramework
              "TargetFrameworkIdentifier"
              "TargetFrameworkVersion"
              "MSBuildAllProjects"
              "ProjectAssetsFile"
              "RestoreSuccess"
              "Configurations"
              "TargetFrameworks"
              "RunArguments"
              "RunCommand"
              "IsPublishable"
            ]

    let loggedMessages = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<string>()
    let msBuildExec = Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.msbuild (Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.MSBuildExePath.DotnetMsbuild "dotnet") (fun exePath args -> Utils.runProcess loggedMessages.Enqueue projDir exePath (args |> String.concat " "))
    let gp () = Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.getProperties (["TargetPath"; "IsCrossTargetingBuild"; "TargetFrameworks"] @ additionalInfo)

    let additionalArgs = additionalMSBuildProps |> List.map (Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.MSBuild.MSbuildCli.Property)

    let cliList = [Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.getFscArgs; Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.getResolvedP2PRefs; gp]

    file |> Dotnet.ProjInfo.Inspect.getProjectInfos loggedMessages.Enqueue msBuildExec cliList additionalArgs
```