# Let ParseAndCheckFileInProject recognize symbols from Nuget dependecies

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

When using `FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices.FSharpChecker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject` from [FSharp Compiler Service](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service) for whole-project analysis, how can NuGet dependencies be included for symbolic resolution?

In the project under analysis, some project file (`*.fsproj`) contains some `<PackageReference>` element, e.g. `<PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.0.3" />`, and some source file contains an open statement `open NodaTime` and somewhere some symbol `DateInterval` refering to `NodaTime.DateInterval`. For me, the FSharp Compiler Service seems to fail to resolve `DateInterval` to `NodaTime.DateInterval` in that source file.

What I am currently doing is, summarized:

```
let checker = FSharpChecker.Create()
let options: FSharpProjectOptions = { ... }
checker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject (...)
```

Given that I use `ParseAndCheckFileInProject`, what is necessary for `checker` and/or `options` to consider symbols coming from NuGet dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to extract the `FSharpProjectOptions` from the `.fsproj` project file. For old-style .NET Framework projects, there used to be a method called `ProjectCracker.GetProjectOptionsFromProjectFile` that would do this, but it has been replaced with `Dotnet.ProjInfo`, which also supports .NET Core. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874904/projectcracker-with-netstandard-2-0-projects) for details.